# Cleaning clothes before Shabbos and Yom Tov

Tags: shabbat, clothing, yom-tov, cleaning, kavod

The Shulchan Aruch in Orach Chaim Siman 242 writes that it was from Takkanas Ezra that one should clean their clothes on Thursday because of "Kavod Shabbos". The Mishneh Brurah in Sif-Katan 5 explains that it shouldn't be done on Erev Shabbos in order that one should be available to take care of the needs of Shabbos (other needs, food, etc.)

In Hilchos Rosh HaShanah (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim Siman 581 Sif 4) it says that one should clean their clothes and take a hair cut Erev Rosh HaShanah. Why in this case of Erev Yom Tov does it not apply the takkana of Ezra mentioned in Siman 242 (that one should clean their clothes from 2 days before Shabbos in order to take care of the needs for Shabbos.) Does the needs of yom tov somehow differ in this regard?

Comment: You don't need to prepare food before yom tov

Comment: @DoubleAA Source? I'm allowed to licatchila push off *all* cooking and food preparation for yom tov?

Comment: Only if you want it to taste nice and fresh

Comment: @DoubleAA What about if it's things that will stay fresh still from the day before? Sources?

Comment: @Yehoshua Are you looking for a source that you're allowed to cook on Yom Tov? I think it shouldn't be too hard to find one.

Comment: @Daniel no I'm looking for the source that one can lichatchila leave ALL food cooking and preparation for yom tov

Comment: I said it wasn't ALL. I don't understand what your hava amina is. They didn't have refrigeration! Of course they cooked a lot on Yom Tov (especially a two day one like RH)! That's why it was so much nicer than Shabbat. What reason could you have for forbidding cooking on Yom Tov?

Comment: Yehoshua, everything is permitted in Judaism unless there's reason to forbid it. You can't demand a source that something is permitted.

Comment: @Yehoshua Do you have a source that leaving all cooking for yom tov would not be permitted lichatchila? It seems like the burden of proof is on you. I can't imagine why it wouldn't be permitted.

Comment: @Daniel Why is it then there are some things that are ossur to do on Yom Tov if they were not done from before Yom Tov?